# How to set a variable for Controller from HttpInterceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am building a Spring Boot application.

I like to set a variable for the Spring Boot application. This variable should be set in an HTTP interceptor. The reason I do this, this variable will store some ID, and this ID will be used in methods in every controller.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You SET the variable in an HTTP interceptor?
So it's not a unique global variable, it's an ID that is different for every request? That's what request attributes are for:

```
@Component
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response,
                             Object handler) throws Exception {
        if(request.getMethod().matches(RequestMethod.OPTIONS.name())) {
            return true;
        }
        request.setAttribute("MY_ID", generateId(...));
        return true;
    }


}

@Controller
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(...)
    public String something(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
        System.out.println( req.getAttribute("MY_ID"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Works well! Thanks! but why do we return if method is OPTION ?

Comment: I saw the OPTIONS exception is some sample code. It's supposed to only return headers for CORS, so it should not do any business logic. But it will pass through the preHandle, so you can filter it out explicitly there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass it as JVM args and use it using System.getProperty.
2. Use -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--interceptor.enabled=true and keep a backup config in application.properties or using -Drun.arguments and access the property key directly in your interceptor